# Making Apache recognize MIME type of files without extension

Tags: linux, debian, apache-2.2, mime

I have some old HTML files that were created elsewhere by someone else.  Many of them don't, for some reason, have the .html extension on them.  I don't want to have to change them if possible, but for some reason Apache can't seem to do any MIME magic to figure out their file type.  I have the *mime_magic* mod enabled, along with the following in the *sites* section:

```
    MimeMagicFile /etc/magic
```

I should note that I'm using Debian Linux on this machine.

Comment: Is the file `/etc/magic` actually the right location on your system for the MIME magic file?

Comment: Mind that mod_mime_magic only kicks in if mod_mime does not find a MIME type for a file. In case of no extension, mod_mime finds *many* MIME types from /etc/mime.types, causing mod_mime_magic to not ever being called, but also not *one* type being determined.

Answer (score 6):

I tried the DefaultType workaround in my main conf file and it did not work for me. (My environment is an internal, thoroughly hacked-up version of Apache, so there may be a FileInfo directive or something overriding DefaultType and I can't find it. On standard installations it may work...)

What DID work: since all the extensionless files I'm dealing with are in one known directory, I added a Location block and used ForceType:

```
<Location "/directoryname">
ForceType text/plain
</Location>
```

You cannot use ForceType on a directory that should contain more than one type of file.

Answer (score 5):

Assume all files not containing a period are PHP:

```
      <FilesMatch "^[^\.]+$">
              ForceType application/x-httpd-php
      </FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple warkaround, not really a solution maybe, would be to change the **DefaultType** as follows:

> DefaultType text/html

This would assure every non recognized file will be treated as html.

This is not a true solution, I repeat, but it is simple and may have sense if your server serves mainly html contents

Answer (score 1):

The magic file path is `/usr/share/file/magic` in Debian. Change the configuration statement to

```
MimeMagicFile /usr/share/file/magic
```

If you open `/etc/magic` with a text editor, you can see the comment explaining that `file(1)` should use that file for your *local* magic definitions only.

Comment: It seems like this should work, but Apache is still giving text/html for those files, and I just double checked to make sure the file is there.

Comment: oops, I mean text/plain

Comment: Actually, I think I take that back.  It might be something with Firefox because I just checked this with Chromium, and it seemed to work just fine.

Comment: And that only seems to be on some files.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me that you are using the *SYSTEM* magic file when you want to be using the *MIME* magic file — as the name of the Apache configuration directive "MimeMagicFile" implies.  Try this:

```
MimeMagicFile /usr/share/mime/magic
```

Of course, make sure that is the right path for your system — I don't have a Debian system to test with, but I would expect it to be there.  Try `locate mime/magic` if you can't find it at the above location.